# Telegram python bot (telebot library)

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, telebot

I use the library  telebot on python for my telegram bot. I need that when clicking on the first  button (`InlineKeyboardButton`) from `markup` another markup with few buttons (`InlineKeyboardMarkup`) should shown.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types


#BOT CONNECT
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

#markups
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Почати ", ))
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Show guide",url=""))


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id, "Бот буде надсилати вам вибірку найголовніших новин на вибрану вами тему у вибраний час", reply_markup=markup)


# RUN
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Почати", callback_data="test"))
```

or

```
keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Почати", callback_data="test"))
```

and

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def testing(call):
  if call.data == "test":
     bot.send_message(call.chat_id, "send text")
  else:
     pass
```

open the button like this and check like this don't forget to put the decarator